# How to think the range of the parameter?

Tags: calculus, geometry, definite-integrals

An exercise asks to compute the length of the arc length.
The curvilinear equation is
$$ \left(\frac xa\right)^{2/3} + \left(\frac yb\right)^{2/3} = 1\ \ (a>0,b>0,a \neq b)  $$
I use $\cos(t)$ and $\sin(t)$ to substitute $\left(\frac xa\right)^{2/3}$ and $\left(\frac yb\right)^{2/3}$.

So 
$$ x = a\cos^3(t)   \\y = b\sin^3(t) $$

And how to ascertain the range of $t$ ?

The reference says $t \in \left ( 0,2\pi \right ) $ , but why not $\left( -\frac \pi2, \frac \pi2 \right )$ ? they are both can get the range $\left (-1,1\right)$

Comment: Your range covers only the half of the elliptic monster.

Comment: @zoli Now I know where I was wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=b=1$.
Here is the diagram when $0\le t\le 2\pi$:

[image]

Here $-1 \le \cos(t)\le 1$ and $-1 \le \sin(t)\le 1$.

And here it is when $-\frac{\pi}{2}\le t \le \frac{\pi}{2}:$

[image]

Here, $0 \le \cos(t)\le 1$ and $-1 \le \sin(t)\le 1$.

Comment: Now I know the range of t need to include the whole arc. Thank you.

Comment: @Tony: If my answer helped the pplease accept it by clicking on the check mark.